# useState set method doesn't update value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React and I am trying to make a login page that keeps the values of the users, but my variable `context` keeps the default values.

I created a hook :

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

export const stateContext = createContext();

const getFreshContext = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('context') == null) {
        localStorage.setItem('context', JSON.stringify({
            memberId: 0,
            firstname: ""
        }));
    }
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('context'));
};

export default function useStateContext() {
    const { context, setContext } = useContext(stateContext);
    return {
        context,
        setContext: obj => {
            setContext({ ...context, ...obj })
        }
    };
}

export function ContextProvider({ children }) {
    const [context, setContext] = useState(getFreshContext());

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(context); //returns old values
        localStorage.setItem('context', JSON.stringify(context));
    }, [context]);

    return (
        <stateContext.Provider value={{ context, setContext }}>
            {children}
        </stateContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Here is the login :

```
//some code 

    const login = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (validate()) {
            createAPIEndpoint(ENDPOINTS.members).getByTwo(values.email, values.password)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    setContext({ memberId: data.id, firstname: data.firstName });
                  
                    console.log(data.id); //returns good values
                    console.log(context); //returns old values
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
            navigate('/planner');
        }
    };

return (
        <form onSubmit={login}>
        //some code
       </form>
    );
```

I know that it doesn't update immediately, but I don't get that even when I navigate to my other page I still have the default values.

Comment: Did you wrap you context provider around your app?

Comment: @RubenSmn Yes, ContextProvider is around my app